# Formula to calculate if 0

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

See the following image:

[image: Apple & Orange]

In cell B5 I have `=(AND(IF(B2=0,SUM(2+2),0),IF(B3="",SUM(2+2),0)))` and it is saying TRUE, instead of calculating and giving me 4. I don't know why.

What I want is, if I enter 0 for Apple in cell B2 and leave cell B3 for Orange blank (must be blank or an error will appear), only then I want cell B5 to calculate 2+2=4. Now, if I enter 0 for Orange in cell B3 and leave cell B2 for Apple blank (must be blank or an error will appear), then I want cell B5 to have a value of 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
=IF(AND(B2=0, B3=""), SUM(2,2),0)
```

So, in your case, you will be looking to input:

```
=IF(AND(B2 = "", B3 = ""), "Error", IF(AND(B2=0, B3=""), (1+(K17*4))*K31),0))
```

Originally, you were not returning a sum, you were returning a boolean (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) from the `=AND()` statement.  Since `=AND()` was on the outside, you were not returning what you wanted.  If you want to return a *value*, you must use the `=IF()` statement in Excel.  Also, you do not need to do `=SUM(2+2)`, you can just calculate `2+2`.  Furthermore, you do not need to calculate `=SUM(1+(K17*4))*K31)` because all of your elementary operations are taken care of in your formula inside the `=SUM()` function.

Comment: What if I have a formula that is more complex than sum(2+2). My actual formula is `=SUM((1+(K17*4))*K31)`

Comment: Oh, I see what you are looking for now.  Let me edit,

Comment: Also both cells can't be blank. Right now with your updated formula, my answer doesn't change if both the cells are blank. I want an error in the answer cell (B5) if both cells are blank.

Comment: `=IF(AND(B2 = "", B3 = ""), "Error", IF(AND(B2=0, B3=""), (1+(K17*4))*K31),0))`

Comment: Thank you! for your help

Answer (score 0):

Using the below function works;

> =IF(AND(B2=0;B3="");SUM(2+2);IF(AND(B2="";B3=0);0;"Error Message"))

In this case, if B2 is 0, and B3 is blank, you'll get your formula `(SUM(2+2))`.
If B2 is blank, and B3 = 0, you'll get value 0.
In all other cases (e.g. Both blank), you will get the error message.